# Что понимается под единым интерфейсом в REST?

Tags: java, rest

Начал разбираться с `REST` архитектурой, и среди ограничений есть:

> "Клиенты отделены от сервера единым интерфейсом"

[Статья в которой этот пункт первый в ограничениях архитектуры REST, но в других написано примерно то-же самое.](https://html-templates.info/blog/znakomtes-arhitektura-REST)

Но что в данном случае понимать под интерфейсом? В статье написано что клиенты не отвечают за хранилище данных, так они в любом случае не отвечают за базу обычный `mvc` и так попадает в это условие если использовать `jsp`. В веб приложение мы обращаемся к серверу который в свою очередь работает с сервлетами прикрепленными к URL'ам а сервлеты уже используют API модуля для работы с базой(поправьте пожалуйста если я не прав). А в чем тогда `REST` вообще выражается? Что он вносит в цепочку взаимодействий: `база <-> обработка бизнес логики <-> UI` ?

Что понимать под интерфейсом? И что значит единым или не единым?

Comment: добавьте контекст в вопрос. без контекста сложно понять, что имел ввиду автор.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагаю, что имеется в виду унифицированный (unified) интерфейс. Т.е. независимо от функциональности системы её интерфейс не будет отличаться. Это позволяет облегчить создание клиентов и серверов.

Comment: но как такое вообще возможно если в базе будут появляться новые таблицы тоесть предметная область проекта расширяется, вместе с ней появляются и новые данные про которые раньше было вообще не известно то любое обращение к этим данным будет требовать расширения интерфейса. Или ... есть какой-то выход?

Comment: в другом ответе (который стоит выбрать) описано как это можно сделать - **HATEOAS**. лучше возьмите более свежую статью и желательно на английском.

Answer (score 1):

[**Единообразие интерфейса**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST#4._.D0.95.D0.B4.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.84.D0.B5.D0.B9.D1.81.D0.B0)

Наличие унифицированного интерфейса является фундаментальным требованием дизайна REST-сервисов Унифицированные интерфейсы позволяют каждому из сервисов развиваться независимо.

К унифицированным интерфейсам предъявляются следующие четыре ограничительных условия:

- Идентификация ресурсов
- Манипуляция ресурсами через представление
- «Самоописываемые» сообщения
- Гипермедиа, как средство изменения состояния приложения (HATEOAS)